# REST API - CRUD operations on bulk of objects

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture

I am designing a **RESTful API** and would like to understand how to perform CRUD operations on **bulk** of objects.

For example, I would like to **delete 30 users** at **once**. How to design such an option in terms of **REST API**?
Or may be this is not a **good practice**?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can design it in this way.

```
@Path("/users")
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response deleteUsers(args) {
.........
}
```

You can pass your list of users in a json (forexample user ids) as part of your request.

or you can use matrix params to pass the list of user ids (if the number of users are less).